# why maximum (w/w) percent concentration of commercial acids is same to their molar mass?

Tags: concentration

i want to know why maximum (w/w) percent concentration of commercial acids is same to their molar mass, for example for HCl the maxmim concentration is 37 and it's molar mass is 36.5 and maximum concentration of H2SO4 is 98%(w/w) and it's molar mass is 98.
thanks alot!

Comment: I think this is just a coincidence. As you may have already noticed, the molar mass is not *exactly* the same as the maximum concentration.

Answer (score 1):

It's a coincidence as HBr is 48% (MW ~81), phosphoric acid is 85% (~98), hydrofluoric acid 97% (MW ~20).Look here for more http://www.csudh.edu/oliver/chemdata/acid-str.htm

Comment: Bon. We must have posted at the same time. Apologies